# Decay pressure altitude

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

Under the assumptions of isothermal layer and ideal gas, derive the equation of
exponential decay of pressure with respect to altitude using the calculus method: cut a
small piece of air of thickness equal to dz and base area equal to A as shown in Fig.
and then integrate all the small pieces together from altitude $z_1$ to $z_2$ with corresponding
pressure from $p_1$ to $p_2$. Eventually, one can derive the following
$$ p_2=p_1 e^{\frac{z_1-z_2}{h}} $$

[Hint: The figure indicate that the small pressure increment may be written as
dp = −ρgdz. The state equation of ideal gas is assumed to hold: pV = nRT.
The density ρ = n/V .]}

Extra Go through the derivation and find h as a function of R, T and g

---

Attempt

$$\begin{aligned}
P(z+\Delta x)A -P(z)A&=\rho_{air}g \Delta z *g
\\ \frac{P(z+\Delta z)-P(z)}{\Delta z }=\rho_{air} g
\\ \frac{dP}{dz}=\rho_{air} g
\end{aligned} $$
From Diff Eq $$\begin{aligned}
p(z)&=P_0 e^{\rho_{air}g*z} 
               \\    &=p_{0}e^{\frac{M_{air} P_{abs}}{RT}*z}
\end{aligned}$$

---

**Cant see how** $$ p_2=p_1 e^{\frac{z_1-z_2}{h}} $$
**was derive** thinking diff assmptions were made

---

---

a  hand drawn pic and free body diagram  Give me a min

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the ideal gas law yet? Think about what $h$ represents. Also, think about the bounds of pressure when you integrate. You may want to write out more steps.

Comment: not sure . h is height?? think that I did use Ideal gas law. or h is the middle of the square height. IDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given $dp = − \rho gdz$.
Your error, although you do not realise it, is that the density $\rho$ depends on the pressure.
Use the extra information that are give to find out how the density depends on the pressure.
Substitute for the density in the equation for $dp$ and do the integration.
You should now be able to call a constant in your pressure equation $h$ to get the required equation for pressure.